# Что быстрее: include или file_get_content?

Tags: php

Что быстрее: include или file_get_content?

Comment: readfile не подойдет. мне нужно просто файл прочитать и все. Так что быстрее???

Comment: include конечно же

Comment: Влад ты и тут успеваешь, но киллер мне уже сказал что include использовать надо для подключения php кода а file_get_contents для чтения простого текста.

Comment: Слишком разное предназначение чтобы сравнивать их *на скорость*.

Answer (score 4):

- `include` выполняет кучу разных действий помимо простого чтения файла, соответственно, если вам не требуется выполнять `evaluate` для содержимого файла, то `include` ни к чему.
- `file_get_contents` читает содержимое в память, что вполне себе может стать критичным. Для целенаправленного вывода в некоторый `output` рекомендуют использовать [`readfile()`.](https://www.php.net/readfile)

> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328301/is-file-get-contents-slower-than-include
> - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909672/file-get-contents-or-readfile-for-displaying-filesystyem-image

Comment: Мне просто сказали что file_get_contents грузит сервер. я вот теперь хочу узнать что быстрее

Comment: @Deert

- Если вас интересует производительность для **вашего конкретного случая** - возьмите и замерьте.

- Теоретическую разницу между `file_get_contents,` `readfile` и `include` я описал, подробнее и с бенчмарками - сходите по предоставленным ссылкам *(по их бенчмарку выходит, что разница несущественная).*

- Единственная фундаментальная разница `file_get_contents` и `readfile`, судя по всему, в использовании памяти. Критично это для вас или нет, я решить, естественно, не могу.

- Не страдайте `premature optimization`. Если производительность перестанет устраивать, тогда уже можно думать.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, include() не "читает файл", а тупо подставляет содержимое "инклюжеемого" файла в то место, где вызван инкуд.

---
file_get_contents() также отличается от include() тем, что не позволяет читать PHP код (кэп=)), например.

---
И кстати, о каком "оценивании файла" идет речь?

Comment: @Asen

- Хорошо, что вы умеете пользоваться гуглопереводчиком :)

- [\[Документация по `include`\]][1] The include statement includes and **evaluates** the specified file.

- Разумеется, понятно, что `include` равносилен `eval(get_file_contents(...))` с точностью до используемого механизма кэширования, но в зависимости от поведения `eval` будет меняться поведение `include`.

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, а вы, как понимаю, с ним дружите? =)

Comment: @Asen Ну, бывает, перекинемся парой слов.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос, если файл находится локально - то, конечно же, file_get_contents выполнится быстрее :)

Правда я опускаю тот факт что результат работы будет не идентичен :)

Comment: Всем спасибо решил юзать file_get_contents()